# How to reordering rows in NSTableView with NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

i've got `NSArrayController` which gives my `NSTableView` object data from array `_files`.
The problem is i want to reorder rows by dragging. How can i do this correclty with `NSArrayController`?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this article in [Red Sweater Blog](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/274/a-moveable-beast) of use.

In it, the author subclasses NSArrayController in order to provide this functionality in a bindings-oriented application.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think ArrayController gives you this feature.

You have to manually implement by codes all the required methods and update the datasource by making object of same arrayController.

Now Binding is still under growing phase and every year we are seeing some new features added,
and I hope in near future Cocoa Binding will grow stronger with all these features.